Swift Type Aliasing like C# possible?
I want to have the following types:

Renderable = Protocol/Interface with function render()
Bag<T> = Renderable, OrderedDictionary<String, T> where T = Renderable
Bag = Bag<Renderable> (shorthand without T-type specification, just assuming it is Renderable)

This will ensure, I can render() everything. And in Bag I can store anything Renderable, either providing the specific types or not.
The C# version looks like this:
public class Bag : Bag<object> {}
public class Bag<T> : Dictionary<string, T> {
    public override string ToString() => ToString("");      
    public string ToString(string separator) => string.Join(separator, this.Values);
}

Trying to translate this into Swift:
public protocol Renderable {
    func render() -> String
}

import OrderedCollections

public typealias Bag<T> = OrderedDictionary<String, T> where T: Renderable

extension Bag: Renderable {
    public func render() -> String {
        render(separator: "")
    }
    
    public func render(separator: String = "") -> String {
        if count == 0 { return ""}
        return map {
            $0.value.render()  <-- compilers says: value has no member "render"
        }.joined(separator: separator)
    }
}

Q1: Why does Swift think, $0.value, which is a T, which is constraint to Renderable has no function render()?
Q2: How would I define a simple type Bag like the C# version, like
public typealias Bag = Bag<Renderable>


Since you want to store any type that conforms to Renderable in your dictionary you can simply skip the generic T in the typealias and directly use the protocol instead
public typealias Bag = OrderedDictionary<String, Renderable> 


You need to also write the constraint on the extension,
extension Bag: Renderable where Value : Renderable {
    // ...
}

Note that you should use the type parameter name declared in OrderedDictionary (Value), not the type parameter name declared in your type alias (T).
This has been submitted as an issue on the swiftlang repo.

There is no such thing as Bag<any Renderable> (written as Bag<Renderable> in older versions), because any Renderable itself is not Renderable, so it does not fulfil the constraint. You can, however, declare:
// Unlike C#, the type parameter arity of a type is not part of the type's name, 
// so you cannot declare another type called "Bag"
public typealias AnyBag = OrderedDictionary<String, any Renderable>

any Renderable is an existential type, so (similar to C#) if you insert value types into this dictionary, they will get boxed.

This leads to: "No type for 'Value' can satisfy both 'Value == any Renderable' and 'Value : Renderable'"

@user3719421 I think you must have misunderstood the answer, or are using the types incorrectly. See the fiddle.
